# How Do I Find the Exact solution after using the Finite Difference Method?

Tags: numerical-methods

My starting equation is $y'' = \frac{wx}{2EI}(L-x)$   [Beam Formula]

I got my approximations, but how do I use that to find the exact equation?
I know that y = y(homogeneous) + y(particular).

But the homogeneous solution would come from $y'' = 0$. 
How do I even use that to find the homogeneous solution with my characteristic equation?

Also, I find that my particular solution is also zero. (Guessing that the answer to: $y'' = 0$ is $y1 = y2 = 0$.)

Help, thanks.

Comment: Your expressions are hard to read. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). As for the question (if I understand it correctly), in general an approximation doesn't help you find the exact solution. Hence, it is used when no exact solution is available. Otherwise, why even use a numerical method?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to use numerical methods. I don't know which one to use.

Comment: Your title says "finite differences", I assume this is the method you wanted to use? Honestly, I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: This method is what I'm referring to: http://mathforcollege.com/nm/mws/gen/08ode/mws_gen_ode_spe_finitedif.pdf I cant understand what he does on page five to solve for his homogeneous solution

Comment: Are you trying to solve the equation (E.1.1)? Cause that is not the equation you have written in this question. You missed a term

Comment: But if you really want to solve the equation you written here, then the homogeneous solution is the general solution of $y''=0$ which is just a linear function $Ax+B$

Comment: I really have no idea how to solve that. Just like in that document, I made my matrix, got my values. how would I set up my homogeneous and particular equations in order to follow the next steps?

Comment: Jackie, finding an exact solution is certainly possible here (and I just hinted you the homogeneous part), and it's also possible to get a numerical solution. But those two things are not related to each other. Aside from originating from the same equation

Comment: Right..Ax+B. Doesn't that mean there are infinite homogeneous solutions? How Do I know what to pick. Does it matter?

Comment: You usually have initial or boundary conditions... Which are also necessary to get any sensible numerical solution

Comment: So if I have i(1) = 0, i(2) = -1.47, i(3) = -1.47, and i(4) = 0. How Do I use that? I really need guidance here.

Comment: What is $i$? I still don't understand what you are trying to do, and I can't study the PDF you linked in detail right now. Maybe you could clarify what and why are you trying to do and I will come back in a few hours

Comment: I'm trying to approximate the deflection of the beam, with its moment function described by the differential equation: M = w/2(L-x)^2.                                                  So, y'' = w/2(L-x)^2.                                                                                                                     I then substitute y'' for the central divided difference formula in order to approximate y(2) and y(3). Beam mechanics has it so that the deflection of beams are 0 at the supports --> y(1) and y(4) = 0. So I sub the CDD form and the values of w, E, I, and L. Make a linear syste

Comment: Then I solve the linear system for my solutions:                                                                              y(1) = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                   y(2) = -1.47                 y(3) = -1.47                 y(4) = 0                             I am now trying to compare this approximated value to the exact value. But I don't know how to derive the equation for this exact value. (Compare by relative true error btw)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is impossible. Finite difference methods are a way to generate numerical approximations to the solution of an equation, no more, no less. Exact solutions, when they exist, require different techniques to derive.

Comment: Then what is this guy: http://mathforcollege.com/nm/mws/gen/08ode/mws_gen_ode_spe_finitedif.pdf

doing on page 5 after getting his matrix of approximated values at those nodes.

Comment: It appears he is using a completely different technique in order to derive the “exact” solution to the differential equation, in order to compare the relative accuracy of the finite difference method. The point is that the finite difference method is unable to provide exact solutions, and is meant primarily for cases where exact solutions are exceedingly difficult or even impossible to derive.